# using a function inside an excel IF and use its return value

Tags: excel

I use excel for my budget. The top row has the dates when I am paid. I wrote a function called Between which determines if the date I am suppose to pay a particular bill will occur within the timeframe specified in Between. If it does, it will fill the cell with the correct value, otherwise blank. The arguments for Between are Between([cell with start date],[number of days in period], [date to test is in the period],[value to fill cell if date in period]). So, say A1 has 9/1/2014. Between(A1,14,7,500) would put 500 in the cell since the 7th is between 9/1 and 9/15. If A1 was 9/20/2014, the cell would be blank since the 7th is not between 9/20 and 10/4.

I would like to check if Between returns a value vs a blank so I could fill empty cells with a 0 so I can sum up numbers in a row. Suppose I had this expression in a cell say B12:

`=IF(ISBLANK(Between(A1,14,7,500),0,?)` I want the ? to be the value of Between in the IF statement. How can I get the value of Between into the cell if Between does not return blank?

Answer (score 0):

Just repeat it:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Between(A1,14,7,500)),0,Between(A1,14,7,500))
```

Answer (score 0):

The [N function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/n-function-HP010062398.aspx) converts non-numbers to 0, so you could try:

```
=N(Between(A1,14,7,500))
```